# python subprocess.run if you re-direct stdout/stderr, it error exits instead of working

Tags: linux, python-3.x, subprocess

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os

if False:
    # create log file.
    kfd = os.open( 'kk.log', os.O_WRONLY )

    # redirect stdout & err to a log file.
    os.close(1)
    os.dup(kfd)
    os.close(2)
    os.dup(kfd)

subprocess.run([ "echo", "hello world"], check=True )

% ./kk.py
hello world
%
```

The above works fine, but if you try edit file, and replace False with true:

```
% ./kk.py
% more kk.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./kk.py", line 16, in <module>
  subprocess.run([ "echo", "hello world"], check=True )
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
  output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['echo', 'hello world']' returned
```

non-zero exit status 1.
   %

We don't get the output, and the process error exits...
I would have expected it to just work, writing to kk.log.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to say something like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os

if True:
    # create log file.
    kfd = os.open( 'kk.log', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT )

    # redirect stdout & err to a log file.
    os.dup2(kfd, 1)
    os.dup2(kfd, 2)

subprocess.run([ "echo", "hello world"], check=True )
```

Notice the use of [`os.dup2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.dup2). There are two reasons for that. First and foremost, resulting file descriptors are inheritable. Your echo had no open `stdout`/`-err` actually and hence failed (You can run the following in shell to echo with just stdout closed to check out the behavior: `/bin/echo hello world 1>&-`). Also note, it may not always hold true that if I closed `stdout` (1), the lowest descriptor (and result of [`os.dup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.dup)) is 1. Someone could have closed your `stdin` (0) before running the script (same goes for `stderr`).

The background story to file descriptors inheritance is in the [PEP-446](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/).

I've also added `os.O_CREAT`, since my first failure trying to reproduce your problem was non-existing kk.log.

Needless to say, unless trying to play with interfaces into the os (perhaps as a an exercise), I guess you should normally stick to `subprocess` itself.

Comment: That works! why is it (how do you know) that fd's that are dup()'ed are not heritable (close-on-exec flag is clear), but those created by dup2() are? I never it set or cleared that bit.  This is a shrunken example from a bigger code, so yeah, the assumption is stdout and stdin where not closed.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail and make function names links to docs (where the inheritance bit is actually mentioned). I've also added a link to the PEP-446 that explains everything in a lot more detail. The problem essentially is. Descriptors resulting from `os.dup` in Python >=3.4 are marked to be closed on `execve` (that also affects use of `subprocess.run`).

Comment: Just closing the loop. This information is excellent.  My eventual solution was an if statement for python3.5 and later to use subprocess.run(  close_fds=False ) which is good for my use case.